# android ProgressBar is changing height dimension of parent LinearLayout

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a bunch of RelativeLayout inside LinearLayout. Inside this will be ProgressBar and other elements.

The problem at the moment is that the ProgressBar is extending the height dimension of the parent LinearLayout when placed inside the RelativeLayout.

Here's the basics of what I have.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/timer1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/timer2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The ProgressBar looks like it is extending height of the parent LinearLayout by the height of the ProgressBar. Which of course is not wanted.

Bare in mind that the above LinearLayout is inside another vertical LinearLayout where weightSum="3". So this distortion of the height means all will not fit in the screen vertically.

The one flaw I may have in my thinking is that because I have not yet completed the code (not put ProgressBar in each of the three levels) that it's just a quirk. I'll do that and report back. But it still seems to me this can't be a good thing.

Comment: change the  _android:layout_height="wrap_content"_ of your first relative layout. Just try  it I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/timer1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/timer2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

</LinearLayout>



when using weights use the width or the height to 0dp which ever orientation u need
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there you go. After I filled all three levels of the outer LinearLayout (not visible in example code above), the layout seemed to sort itself out.

All height parameters are the same (each taking up one third of the height of the screen) and this is true in both the xml Preview pane and when tested on an emulator.

So it looks to me that if you have a weightSum of 3, then the layout will not balance out until you have actually written the code for all three weight divisions.

For example, this would work:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:wieghtSum="3" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/example_text" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/example_text" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/example_text" />
<LinearLayout/>
```

But the following would **potentially** show a distorted height of the text views because the code is incomplete. weightSum is set to 3 but only code for two of the three divisions is written.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:wieghtSum="3" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/example_text" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/example_text" />
<LinearLayout/>
```